# UITableViewCell is not expanding to fit height of UILabel, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What I want is my `UITableViewCell` to expand/shrink based on the height of the `UILabel` inside.

I have tried just about every solution I could find and it's not working. Maybe I have some setting that's preventing it.

Here is a screenshot of the `UITableViewCell` settings:

[image]

For the `UILabel` inside, `Lines` is set to `0` and `Line Break` to `Word Wrap`.

In the `UIViewController` where I'm showing the table view, I am setting this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tableView.reloadData()
```

And in `cellForRowAt` after dequeuing the cell I'm doing (instructionText being the UILabel):

`cell.instructionText.numberOfLines = 0`

I've seen this in many tutorials and it works, why not for these cells? The content comes out like this:

[image]

This is driving me crazy! Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Here are the UILabel settings:

[image]

Comment: By using auto-sizing automatic height not feasible (without any code). Please use auto-layout for your requirement

Comment: Make sure you set up constraints for the label field against the Content View of the table cell.

Comment: let me know your instructionText auto-layout constraints.

Comment: @BhaveshNayi added them to the end of my question

Comment: Make height constraint priority less than 1000 for UILabel and try

Comment: Add 'bottom space to superview'

Comment: @saino In your constraints please added label bottom constraints as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check your label constraints

[image]